# Extracting elements from Lists of List in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following data frame

```
    sentence    Entity
0   The 7250 IXR-e series uses the SR OS and is ma...   [['SR OS', 'Operating_System'], ['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
1   The 7250 IXR is managed by the NSP, which prov...   [['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
2   Nokia’s feature-rich 64-bit SR OS addresses th...   [['SR OS', 'Operating_System'],['IP routing', 'Feature']]
3   The 7250 IXR-R6 uses the SR OS and is managed ...   [['SR OS', 'Operating_System'], ['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
4   The 7250 IXR-R6 is managed by the NSP   [['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
5   The NSP provides end-to-end service-aware man...    [['NSP', 'Operating_System'], ['Cloud', 'Innovation'],['IP/MPLS', 'Feature']]
```

I want to split the elements in the entity column into 4 other columns

```
   sentence    Entity                                    e1    et1               e2        et2     
0   The 7250 IXR-e series uses the SR OS and is ma..    SR OS  Operating_System   NSP    Operating_System
```

if there is only one pair of list of list like the secound row , I will be dropping that row, also if the entity column has more than two list of list like the last row I also want to drop that row as well.

I was able to store the first element and apend it a list , post that the idea was to zip all the  list and create a data frame , but i have no idea about  how to extract the other rows...

```
e1 = []
for i in range(10):
    a = (eval(data['Entity'].values.tolist()[i]))
    b = a[0]
    entity_one.append((b[0]))
```

For clear understanding as suggested:

{'sentence': {0: 'The 7250 IXR-e series uses the SR OS and is managed by the Nokia Network Services Platform (NSP).', 1: 'The 7250 IXR is managed by the NSP, which provides integrated network management across the IP network.', 2: 'Nokia’s feature-rich 64-bit SR OS addresses the  full spectrum of IP routing requirements.', 3: 'The 7250 IXR-R6 uses the SR OS and is managed by the Nokia Network Services Platform (NSP).', 4: 'The 7250 IXR-R6 is managed by the NSP'}, 'Entity': {0: "[['SR OS', 'Operating_System'], ['NSP', 'Operating_System']]", 1: "[['NSP', 'Operating_System']]", 2: "[['SR OS', 'Operating_System'], ['IP routing', 'Feature']]", 3: "[['SR OS', 'Operating_System'], ['NSP', 'Operating_System']]", 4: "[['NSP', 'Operating_System']]"}}

Comment: can you `print(df.head(5).to_dict())` and paste the output into your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may first select the wanted list by `apply`ing `len`, and then unpack the list column directly using a list comprehension expression.

### Data

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
    sentence                                            Entity
0   The 7250 IXR-e series uses the SR OS and is ma...   [['SR OS', 'Operating_System'], ['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
1   The 7250 IXR is managed by the NSP, which prov...   [['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
2   Nokia’s feature-rich 64-bit SR OS addresses th...   [['SR OS', 'Operating_System'],['IP routing', 'Feature']]
3   The 7250 IXR-R6 uses the SR OS and is managed ...   [['SR OS', 'Operating_System'], ['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
4   The 7250 IXR-R6 is managed by the NSP               [['NSP', 'Operating_System']]
5   The NSP provides end-to-end service-aware man...    [['NSP', 'Operating_System'], ['Cloud', 'Innovation'], ['IP/MPLS', 'Feature']]
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

# Convert literal list expression to list. Not needed in real use.
import ast
df["Entity"] = df["Entity"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

### Code

```
# 1. select wanted columns (Entity length = 2)
df_ans = df[df["Entity"].apply(len) == 2]

# 2. unpack Entity column, convert to a dataframe, and merge back horizontally
df_ans = pd.concat([
    df_ans[["sentence"]],
    pd.DataFrame(df_ans["Entity"].apply(lambda lsls: [item for ls in lsls for item in ls]).to_list(),
                 columns=["e1", "et1", "e2", "et2"])
], axis=1)

# drop nan's
df_ans = df_ans[~df_ans["sentence"].isna()]
```

### Result

```
print(df_ans)
                                            sentence  ...               et2
0  The 7250 IXR-e series uses the SR OS and is ma...  ...  Operating_System
2  Nokia’s feature-rich 64-bit SR OS addresses th...  ...  Operating_System
3  The 7250 IXR-R6 uses the SR OS and is managed ...  ...               NaN

print(df_ans[["e1", "et1", "e2", "et2"]])
      e1               et1          e2               et2
0  SR OS  Operating_System         NSP  Operating_System
2  SR OS  Operating_System         NSP  Operating_System
3    NaN               NaN         NaN               NaN
```

Comment: hi @Bill Huang the secound sentence is nan , can we not get the respective sentence as well... instead of "nan"

Comment: Drop them using `df_ans = df_ans[~df_ans["sentence"].isna()]`. I have update the answer.